# Why is useState always 'undefined' even after giving it a default value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have tried to pass an empty array as the default value to a `useState` hook in React, but using `console.log(Array.isArray(testing));` or `console.log`ing `testing` seems to always throw an `undefined` to the console no matter the type of variable I pass to it.

```
  const arr = ["b", "a", "n"];
  const { testing, setTesting } = useState(arr);
  console.log(Array.isArray(testing));
  console.log(testing);
```

The problem is that I get the "Cannot read property 'find' of Undefined" in the code of my app, and I don't know how to give a value to testing so the function in my app works.

```
  const { cartItems, setCartItems } = useState([]);
  console.log(Array.isArray(cartItems));

  const onAdd = (product) => {
    const exists = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exists) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exists, qty: exists.qty + 1 } : x
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product, qty: 1 }]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `useState` will give you can an array of `value, and function from which you can change value` not an object. You should use array destructuring instead of object destructuring as `const [ cartItems, setCartItems ] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong syntax

`const { cartItems, setCartItems } = useState([]);`

Here is the correct one

`const [ cartItems, setCartItems ] = useState([]);`